# Pass non-link string with link_to but make it not clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my helper, I'm trying to put "Category » " before my link_to, but obviously not make it not a link, which the code below does.  Not sure the best way to this so I figured I'd pump my breaks and get some help.

This is rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7 (barf i know we're upgrading next week!)

```
 elsif session[:ref].to_f > 0 
    @category = Category.find(session[:ref]).category_name
    link_to  "Category » " + @category, category_catalog_items_path
    end
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if I understand right, you're having trouble making 'Category' "+ @ category on a link? First of all I would suggest using #{} instead of +.

"Category » #{link_to(@category, category_catalog_items_path)}"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Not having trouble making all that a link, the above code produces that fine.  I'd like Category » not to be part of the link, but text.

Comment: Try ="Category » #{link_to(@category, category_catalog_items_path)}", doesnt work?

Comment: this is in a helper, so I took away the = and put "Category » #{link_to(@category, category_catalog_items_path)}" and it worked!!!!    You mind if I edit your answer to this so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry, did not notice this detail! :) Of course not, feel free!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume <s>this is Rails >= 3</s>, and this is code from a helper module. Try this

```
elsif session[:ref].to_f > 0 
    @category = Category.find(session[:ref]).category_name
    "Category » " + link_to  @category, category_catalog_items_path
    end
```

Edit:

This may been contributed from what is likely a bug caused by Rails/Ruby-gems that are out of your control, and if I were really adamant about this, I would do this with client side JavaScript. You should class all your links with some class, lets say ".category", and then jQuery all the links with that class ".category" and then insert Category >> in front of it.

Comment: @jahrichie the older code should still work in Rails 2.3, but if you use Rails 3, the fact that h() is in h("Category >>") becomes important

Comment: Thanks for the response!!! "Category » " + link_to  @category, category_catalog_items_path won't work though :-( , tried that before the post.

Comment: @jahrichie Really, what result did you get? I've tested h("blah") + link_to("blah") on Rails 3 and it worked fine

Comment: I get a 500 error (Status: 500 Internal Server Error), which doesn't make sense, right?  But I definitely tried this as is, and with single quotes too.

Comment: 500 error on a development environment? Sounds like there's something else you should be worried about.

Comment: Right!? But when I remove that code everything is kosher! Regardless, I appreciate you helping me troubleshoot thus far.

Comment: @jahrichie Edited for a stupid and hacky solution that WILL work!

Comment: I'm originally a client-side guy so  this is the first thing that came to mind! Figured rails would have something for this.  BLAHHH.   Much appreciated though!

Comment: "Category » #{link_to(@category, category_catalog_items_path)}" worked! Ugly, but worked!

Comment: @jahrichie glad to hear it worked. However, I would probably still take the time to look at why that 500 error happened. It **should not** happen and might come back in the most unexpected ways.